# Anagram Within an Anagram!

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, poetry, anagram

> The second poem is an anagram of the first poem. Both poems are separated by "~" to indicate they are both anagrams of each other.
>
> ```
> The aim of all is but to nurse the life
> With honour, wealth, and ease, in waning age;
> And in this aim there is such thwarting strife,
> That one for all, or all for one we gage;
> As life for honour in fell battle's rage;
> Honour for wealth; and oft that wealth doth cost
> The death of all, all together lost. 
>
> - W. Shakespeare 
>
> ~ 
>
> How I Ask to Rearrange a Phrase! 
>
> The meaning of life can be found,
> When we turn the letters around;
> If one shuffles well,
> Together, all tell
> A sentence that, hah, should astound! 
>
> To do that goes to start a thrill
> With a brain or a software to fill.
> "Hello" to a fail
> Is worth a high wail —
> So gather the fine game of nil!
> ```
>
> > **Aim:**
>
> Your task is to find the anagram *within* the anagram! There are two distinct groups of words that are anagrams of each other, inside the anagram of Shakespeare's poem. Use both Shakespeare's poem and the entire anagram thereof to deduce what the hidden anagram might be; i.e. what might be the two groups of words that are anagrams of each other!

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The phrase

> "The meaning of life" in the first line of the anagrammed poem

Is an anagram of

> "The fine game of nil" in the last line.

Comment: Well done! Wish I could upvote, but I reached my daily voting limit. You don't need to explain your answer, as how you got to it should be fairly obvious. Do you want the checkmark now, in one to three hours, or in one to three days? :D

Comment: Thank you! Great job on getting such a neat anagram, I imagine it must have taken quite some effort! When you checkmark doesn't really matter, feel free to take your time :)

Comment: Haha, thanks! Anagrams are PriMe in my life ;)

Comment: A belated congratulations (due to bad memory)! $\;\color{green}{\checkmark}$